# my json ajax call return me nothing in the callback, but the data in network

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i am trying to do an ajax call to an external json from my localhost,
when the call is done i am expecting to see the success data to a console.log, but i'm nott seeing it.

In the network instead i see the XHR data, so what i'm doing wrong?

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var citroUrl = 'http://www.citroen.it/_/Layout_Citroen_PointsDeVente/getStoreList'
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "jsonp",
          url: citroUrl ,
          }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }); 

    });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Always check the network tab too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it's only called on success.

Try this to check what's happening:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var citroUrl = 'http://www.citroen.it/_/Layout_Citroen_PointsDeVente/getStoreList'
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: citroUrl,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success', data);
      },
      error: function(err, msg) {
          console.log('err', err);
          console.log('msg', msg);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Diogo is correct. fyi though, if you wanted to assign multiple callbacks on a single request JQuery renamed their ajax functions to: done, fail, always (formally success, fail, complete)  as of JQuery 3.0. so if you're using 3.0 or later use those

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: citroUrl,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(err, data) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
```